# How to share some content in a multisite?

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I'm working on the Drupal 8 multisite where there is main site and partner sites.

For example partners publish events or news.

I want some content from partner sites to be available on the main site. How can this be done?

What I discovered so far:

1. sharing db tables seems tricky - there are just to many node tables and their dependencies will likely break.
2. I could create custom entity but then its not place in "content" (beacause it's not node type) and I will lose nice content handling. but tables are easier to share then.
3. I could copy the content but then i have copies not the same content (what are possibilities here?)

Comment: Drupal 8 has a REST API for nodes built in, consuming that would probably be easiest if you can't share the DB tables

Comment: I think you should detail a bit more about what do you mean by "sharing the content"; I suggest giving an example for such a case and detail about the frequency, etc... Because if it's something small - Manual sharing with an HTML canonical to emphasis the main site could be enough - It's too theoretical to know what nature of data-sharing you are interested in.

Comment: Manual sharing is not possible as the partners wont likely have access to main site and it also should be convenient and automatic.

Comment: The non "program it yourself" way would be to use [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), which unfortunately doesn't have a Drupal 8 release yet

Comment: Provide content from one site via a JSON API for example and then let the other sites fetch the output.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few solutions available in Drupal contrib which allows sites to share the content with each other:

- [Workspace](https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace) In core now creates multiple versions of the site.
- [Entity Pilot](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_pilot) is a really good use core serializer solution. It tracks changes allow and merging via UI. If you want to track the content then you can also use [Entity Pilot Git](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_pilot_git)
  .
- [CPS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cps) D7 version only.
- [Domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) if your site shares the domain name then this is the best solution to display the same content on different domains.
- [Default Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) you have to manually import export the content.
- D8 to D8 migration is the last ditch solution there is no D8 to D8 migration in Drupal core at this moment but you can export content in CSV using [CSV Serialization](https://www.drupal.org/project/csv_serialization) and then import it via [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv). The sites can periodically import or export data in [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/8/hook_cron).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Domain module in Drupal 8 for content sharing .I am not sure about Acquia lift or Acquia Hub , you can check with this option too.